# C Programming. Char Segmentation fault

Tags: c

This is my simple C code and I would like to display 'a' value. However, I'm getting "Segmentation fault" when compiling this program. Please advise.

```
user@linux:~/c$ cat char.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

        char a = 'B';

        printf("test %s\n",a);

        return 0;
}
user@linux:~/c$ gcc -g char.c -o char
user@linux:~/c$ ./char 
Segmentation fault
user@linux:~/c$
```

GNU Debugger

```
user@linux:~/c$ gdb -q char
Reading symbols from char...done.
(gdb) list
1       #include <stdio.h>
2
3       int main(){
4
5               char a = 'B';
6
7               printf("test %s\n",a);
8
9               return 0;
10      }
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/c/char 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a803e0 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x7ffff7dd4620 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, format=<optimized out>, ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffe488) at vfprintf.c:1632
1632    vfprintf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Comment: Compile the program with `-Wall` to get full warnings.

Comment: The argument that goes with `%s` is supposed to be `char*`, not `char`.

Comment: Use `%c` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Elementary, my dear Watson: `printf("test %c\n",a);`

Comment: Please, don't edit the subject to mark as solved, just accept an answer

Comment: and by subject, @Garf365 means the title.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. char*c solved this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Garf365, I would like to accept the answer from Barmar, however I don't see any "check mark beside the answer" as explained in the URL below. Please advise (I'm new to stackoverlow.com)

http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

To accept an answer:

    Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
    To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
    You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: Barmar has not posted an answer, but a comment. You can't accept a comment. see below the 2 answers you've received

Answer (score 3):

It's **undefined behavior** because you have used wrong format specifier for `char` type. So, use `%c` instead of `%s`.

c99 7.19.6.1 paragraph 9:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.225) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding coversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%c` instead of `%s` while print. Because `%s` will try to look for an end of line char, since its is not available in memory it throws an exception.

Try with below one, it will work.

```
int main() {
    char a[2] = {'B','\0'};

    printf("test %s\n",a);

    return 0;
}
```